# Github pages + OAuth

Tags: oauth, github-pages

I'm making a game on a Github Pages in HTML5 and I would like to add a Twitter, Facebook and Google connect to let my users share their results with their friends.

Is there a way to make the complete OAuth flow (request token, signatures, fetch the access token, etc.) on a github page? Do you know a service or a framework which works in a github pages (without backend)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know as far this would help you, but I've recently written a [plugin](https://github.com/krispo/git-connect) that solves the same problem for Github connection.

The problem with providing the complete OAuth flow is related to some [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) limitations of Github API. Suppose, we will encounter with the same problems also for socials api. The only way out of this is to use a tiny proxy server, that can help to complete OAuth process.

[This](https://github.com/krispo/git-proxy) is a tiny sinatra proxy server that I use for Github connection (according to [docs](https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/)). Think it can be quickly extended to socials. Actually, server should be installed only once (for example, to heroku cloud), and then can be used for all your applications.